# Difference of squares under 2024

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm kinda new to stack overflow, so I may not yet get the gist of it, but I have a question that I really want to ask.

How many positive integers less than 2024 cannot be expressed as the difference of the squares of two positive integers?

What I have deduced so far is that the number cannot be a perfect square, it cannot be an odd number, and it has to be in the form 2 * (some other numbers). The first two has to be only to the power of 1, if it is to the power of two or higher, than it can also be written as two squares. Could anyone help me procced from here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in e.g. [Proving expressibility of integers as the difference of two squares.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247853/proving-expressibility-of-integers-as-the-difference-of-two-squares?rq=1), an integer cannot be expressed as the difference of two squares if and only if it is congruent to $2 \pmod{4}$. Thus the integers you need to count are $4 \cdot 0 + 2, 4 \cdot 1 + 2, \dotsc, 4\cdot 505+2$, giving a total of $505+1 = 506$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Comment: As I've said before, I don't accept that any such policy is rational; indeed, by adopting it, you and others have, consciously or unconsciously, been acting perversely. Ultimately, you're free to 'enforce' it by banning my account (one of five years' standing) if you so wish, but until then, I see no reason to spend any more time on this issue.