# What can differences of odd summation be?

Tags: summation, absolute-value

> Let's suppose that we're summing $m$ and $n$ many odd numbers starting
> from $1$ separately, i.e
>
> $$S_m = 1+3+\cdots +(2m-1)$$
>
> $$S_n = 1+3+\cdots +(2n-1)$$
>
> What can their differences be among $37, 42$ and $60$?

I started off with $S_m = m^2$ and $S_n = n^2$, so their difference becomes

$$|S_{m}-S_n| = |m^2-n^2| = |m+n||m-n|$$

But I am not sure what else can be done outside of checking particular values of $n, m$.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that $m+n$ and $m-n$ will have the same parity (odd or even).

Comment: It's not so much that you want to check particular values of $m$ and $n$, but rather particular values of factors $p:=m+n$ and $q:=m-n$ (where we may take $p>q$). That is, if you were looking at potential difference $32$, you'd consider $(p,q)=(32,1), (16,2), (8,4)$. From these candidates, you can determine the corresponding $m$ and $n$ via $m=(p+q)/2$ and $n=(p-q)/2$; candidates that yield integer $m$ and $n$ succeed. (So, what has to be true of $p$ and $q$ for success?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly shown that the set of possible differences between $S_m$ and $S_n$ is the same as the set of positive integers that can be expressed as the difference of two squares. From [Proving expressibility of integers as the difference of two squares.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247853/proving-expressibility-of-integers-as-the-difference-of-two-squares?rq=1), all positive integers *can* be so expressed, except those that are $2 \pmod{4}$, so in particular, $37$ and $60$ are possible, but $42$ is not.